# Php как посчитать кол-во строк в переменной?

Tags: php

Есть переменная:

```
<?php $text = '
строка1
строка2
строка3
';
```

Как посчитать сколько в ней строк?
Пробовал через exlode:

```
$lines = explode('\n', $text);
echo count($lines); //Возвращает 1
```

Пробовал через str_word_count:

```
$lines = str_word_count($text);
echo count($lines); //Возвращает 1
```

Так как все же можно посчитать? Данные получаю из формы, из поля textarea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что символ перевода строки `\n` *(и ему подобные)* нужно писать в двойных кавычках:

```
$text = 'строка1
строка2
строка3';

$lines = explode("\n", $text);
echo count($lines);
```

Возвращает `3`

Comment: странно, неужели тип кавычек так влияет )

Comment: @SdafsFasafs в PHP - да, потому что всё, что в двойных кавычках, будет проверяться на наличие переменных или спец-символов _(как в вашем случае)_, а в одинарных - нет.

Comment: Это не странно. Таков синтаксис php. Строка в двойных кавычках подвергается преобразованию (\n и прочее, имена переменных поставляются), а строка в одинарных кавычках передаётся как есть.

Comment: @SdafsFasafs http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php

Comment: Еще будет полезно знать константу `PHP_EOL` - символ конца строки в данной ОС. Если код никогда не покинет Linux, используйте его (будет "\n").

Answer (score 0):

У меня подобная задача была, когда нужно было задать rows для textarea в зависимости от количиства строк в значении. Написал примерно такой код:

```
$rows = substr_count($text, PHP_EOL) + 1;
```